# How do you control the height of a scrollviewer inside a tabitem?

Tags: wpf

I am having trouble getting the height of a scrollviewer to adjust to whatever the height is of a tabitem.

XAML:

```
<TabItem header="Item">
    <ScrollViewer Height={Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=TabItem}}>
        <Grid>
          .
          .
          .
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</TabItem>
```

When I do this the scrollviewer is only about 50 pixels high. The content inside displays fine. The viewing area height is limited.

I tried this.

```
<TabItem header="Item" x:Name="itemname">
 <ScrollViewer Height="{Binding ElementName="itemname", Path=ViewportHeight}">
```

> The scrollviewer is not limited but when the content inside the
>   scrollviewer grows it goes beyond the viewing area and the scrollbar
>   deos not work.

I have used the first (FindAncestor) example with a StackPanel and it works. Not sure why it won't with a TabItem.

Comment: Interesting note. I tried to set the height of the ScrollViewer to the height of the TabItem in the code behind. It didn't work. When I debugged it the height of the TabItem was Nan. How do I get the height of the TabItem?

Comment: This might explain why the FindAncestor worked with a StackPanel parent. For some reason the height of the TabItem is not being set.

Comment: I gave up and just set the height to a fix number by eyeballing the screen. Too bad I can't figure out a way to do it dynamically.

Comment: It's odd. I thought someone would have figured this out by now.Maybe I just won't use tabcontrol and tabitems.

Comment: It seems that the tabitem height is nebulous and adjusts to the height of its children. So the only way to get the height of the tabitem to what you want is to set the height of its children. That sucks.

Comment: No takers on this. There has to be a way to control the height of the tabitem without hardcoding the height of the scrollviewer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `HorizontalAlignment` / `VerticalAlignment` properties?

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretech">
```

Comment: This has the same effect as binding the height to the ElementName of the TabItem. The height is set to something beyond the viewing area of the TabItem and the scrollbars are disabled.